# I have roughly 91 JTextAreas that I need to display information. What is a way in which I can manage what each JTextArea will display?

Tags: java, jtextarea

There will be 91 Text Areas in which each displays a value. I'm trying to find a more efficient way of approaching this problem rather than just mindlessly adding JTextAreas and attempting to manage the instantiated names of each of the 91 text areas.

I'm open to suggestions of what the ways I could solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: `There will be 91 Text Areas in which each displays a value` - why are you using a text area to display a value.  91 text areas sounds like a poor design. You should probably state your real requirement, not your actual solution. I'm sure we can suggest something better. For example, maybe a JList would be better. Then you just add your value to the ListModel and it will display.

Comment: @camickr For my project, I'm trying to display the attenuation values of 14 radios. There are 91 possible pair combinations of said buoys and each combination needs a attenuation value. 

I'm willing to try a JList approach...it sure sounds better than using 91 text areas .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example:

```
JTextArea myTests[] = new JtextArea[91];
for (int i = 0; i < 91; i++){
    myTests[i] = new JTextArea();
}
```

Then you can refer to these as myTests[index] instead of an instantiated name for each.

Comment: That looks like it could work.. I'm using the Eclipse Windowbuilder right now, and it automatically creates an instantiated name for each instance of JTextArea you create (ie.: textArea_1, textArea_2, textArea_3,...textArea_91). Is there a way that using your given model I could still use the existing instantiated names created by Eclipse?

Comment: You would have to use java reflection if you want to access the fields how you're planning to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/